# Spring Boot API test throwing nullPointerException

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, testing, mocking

So I'm trying to test my api and its giving me a nullpointer exception when I try to use the repository.

Supposedly I have a h2 database for testing in my application.yml(inside test/resources) like this:

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: test
  datasource:
    username:
    password:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;
    platform: h2
```

Here is my ControllerAPItest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase
class ControllerAPITest {



    @Mock
    CompaniaRepository companiaRepository;
    @Mock
    DefaultGroupRepository defaultGroupRepository;
    @Mock
    OfficeRepository officeRepository;

    @InjectMocks
    CompaniaServiceImpl companiaService;

    ControllerAPI controllerAPI = new ControllerAPI(companiaService);



    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        Compania compania = new Compania();
        compania.setName("companiaTest");
        compania.setDominio("dominioTest");
        compania.setAltas("altasTest");
        compania.setBajas("bajasTest");
        compania.setDefault_group(null);
        compania.setOffice(null);

        companiaRepository.save(compania);
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        companiaRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    void getByField() {
    }

    @Test
    void getCompanias() {
        System.out.println(controllerAPI.GetCompanias());
    }
}
```

And here is the output of the error I'm getting:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> controller.ControllerAPI.GetCompanias(ControllerAPI.java:114)     at
> controller.ControllerAPITest.getCompanias(ControllerAPITest.java:65)

It is pointing to the line that says:

> companiaRepository.save(compania);

Here is the full Error: https://textdoc.co/eGmu72wa1ydEoJ4T

What is happening with my code?

Thanks!

Edit. here is my getCompanias in my controller.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @GetMapping()
    public Map<String, List<Compania>> GetCompanias() {
        Map<String, List<Compania>> mappedResult = Collections.singletonMap("result", companiaService.getCompanias());
        return mappedResult;
        // return companiaService.getCompanias();
    }
```

That uses the companiaService here:

```
public List<Compania> getCompanias() {
        return companiaRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: At the point at which you create `controllerAPI`, `companiaService` has not been created. Create `controllerAPI` in an `@Before` method.

Comment: @tgdavies No, but thanks anyway! I think is something related to mocking that it is not instantiating it or something like that :S

Comment: You need to show the code at controller.ControllerAPI.GetCompanias(ControllerAPI.java:114) in your question.

Comment: See my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test setup has a lot of issues, and my suggestion would be to read through the mockito and spring test basics, for instance [here](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-series) and [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing) .

**Test setup**
For starters, the code mixes up different test setups. The annotation `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` suggests a JUnit4 setup, but the strack trace indicates the use of JUnit5, as the jupiter package is on the classpath (`org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution....`). The `@RunWith` can be removed as JUnit5 relies on extensions, and the spring extention (`@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`) is already present as a meta annotation in the `@SpringBootTest` annotation ([source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.java#L81)).

**Use of mock annotations**
When you plan to create a Spring boot test, mocks can be injected in the TestApplicationContext using the `@MockBean` annotation. However, by using `@Mock` together with `@InjectMocks`, the mocks will be created by Mockito only, without being registered in the application context. More info on the differences can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-spring-mockito-mock-mockbean).

**Mock preparation**
Mocks are "fake" implementations of classes, and are used to mimic the behaviour of a real object. Its not a real object and it only performs the tasks you have assigned to it. In the setup() however, the method attempt to access the mock as a real object. This won't work as its not the correct way to set up mock:

```java
    // The CompaniaRepository is annotated as being a mock
    @Mock
    CompaniaRepository companiaRepository;
    ...

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        Compania compania = new Compania();
        ...

        // Here a method on the mock is invoked, which has no use
        companiaRepository.save(compania);
    }
```

More info on setting up a Mockito mock can be found [here](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-behavior).

Furthermore, if you plan to set up a database test I wouldn't suggest on mocking the repositories as it diminishes the requirement of using a database (assuming there isn't a third repository which does require H2).

A final thing; Spring controllers are best tested by performing tests via the web layer. Instantiating the controller under test using `new ControllerApi(...)` will only test the methods, and not the endpoints they are mapped to. A great tutorial on how to test the web layer can be found [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/).